# PHP Class and Function from variable

Tags: php

I am working on a simple router program in PHP.
Here is my function

```
    private function dispatch($dest)
    {
        $goto = explode("@", $dest);

        $controller = $goto[0];
        $action = $goto[1];

        $clocation = require_once("../app/controllers/$controller.php");
        $c = new $controller;


    }
```

Everything works to that point. But, I want to return the results of the action (a method within the class that is instantiated as $c.
I tried :

```
return $c->$action
```

but that doesn't work.
Is there a way to do this, or do I need to try a different approach all together?

thanks

Comment: you forgot the `()` so it think its a property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
return $c->$action();
```

With the `()` for a method/function call.  Otherwise PHP thinks it's a dynamic property of `$c`

You can test this like so:

```
class foo{

    public $bar = 'bar';

    function test(){ return 'test'; }
}

$foo = new foo();

$bar = 'bar';
$test = 'test';

echo $foo->$bar . PHP_EOL;
echo $foo->$test() . PHP_EOL;
```

Outputs

```
bar
test
```

Try it [online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1a757bb2e4cf0c98e908941264cc1ed122384494)

And `$foo->$test` would give you this notice

```
 <br />
 <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: foo::$test in <b>[...][...]</b> on line     <b>16</b><br />
```

Which means you either didn't mention it, don't have error reporting on, or your class has a property with the same name as that method.

Comment: sure, you were this close `> <`